# I want to update qty on checkout page using ajax without page load in magento1

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, checkout-page

When I update my qty page reload I am using this code qty update but when I 
    refresh page

```
 /* here is mu code */
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('.btn-update').on('click',
    function(e){
      e.preventDefault();


        var form = jQuery(jQuery(this).closest('form'));

        // we'll extract the action and method attributes out of the form

        // kick off an ajax request using the form's action and method,
        // with the form data as payload
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            method: form.attr('method'),
            data: form.serializeArray()


        });


    }
);
});
```

Comment: If you want to see the qty update without reloading the page, you need to increment/update the value on the html element too

Comment: how can i do that i am not aware of it

Comment: using javascript, see example : http://jsfiddle.net/uewv81Ld/  - you can add a bit of js code in your existing code to update the right element